# Java: Calculating average GPA with intArr of 12 students

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a script to calculate the average GPA of the class and which shows the lowest and highest grades achieved by the students.
I'm trying how to get the average of the 12 numbers. I know I need to add all the number and divide them 12. Can someone give me a few tips on how I can do this. Thansk!!

Comment: Have a read through this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the 12 students have the grades in the array intArr

```
public int calculateAverage(){

int[] intArr = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12};
//Total number of students grades in the array
int totalStudents = intArr.length;

//Variable to keep the sum
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < totalStudents; i++){
     sum = sum + intArr[i];//Add all the grades together
}

int average = sum/totalStudents;
return average;
}
```

Comment: This would not work. the int has to be declared as an array, otherwise it shows an error.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Java 8 there are good facilities for stats:

```
IntSummaryStatistics stats = Arrays.stream(grades).summaryStatistics();
```

Then you can use `stats.getMin`, `stats.getAverage` etc.

If, on the other hand, this is a homework assignment then you probably should write your own code to do this rather than use the Java library.

Answer (score 0):

What @SiKing said, what code have you tried? Show us what you've coded!

@nitinkc's code is on the right track although not completely correct by OO standards.

Here's what I have. This is just a function. You must implement your runner yourself assuming you have just a main runner class...

```
// initialise and pass in your array into your function
public static double calculateAverage(int[] array) {

    // double because averages are more than likely to have decimals
    double gradesTotal = 0;

    // loop through each item in your array to get the sum
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        gradesTotal = gradesTotal + array[i];
    }

    // return the sum divided by number of grades
    return gradesTotal/array.length;
}
```